# Android Facebook SDK check if share is successful

Tags: android, facebook, callback, share, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an Android application which should allow a user to share a post on Facebook. For statistics, I would like to know if the user has successfully shared a post or decided to cancel.

**Question:** Is there a way to check if post was successfully shared using ShareDialog from Facebook SDK 4.5, without `publish_action` permission?

ShareDialog opens Facebook App share dialog and if the share was successful, `onSuccess` method in the callback function is called (or `onCancel` if user cancels the share dialog). The problem is when user doesn't have a Facebook App installed on his device. Then ShareDialog falls back to default browser for sharing, but callback function `onSuccess` method is always executed in that case, even if user has clicked on the cancel button!

My current code looks like this:

```
FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fb SHARE canceled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fb SHARE error");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

        String postId = result.getPostId();
        if (postId != null)
        {
            // record successful FB share
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fb SHARE success");
        }
    }
}

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, shareCallback);
```

This code works fine, but it requires `publish_actions` permission to check `postId`. Is there some other way to check if sharing was successful, without requiring additional (`publish_actions`) permissions from Facebook (because that's just too painful)?

Comment: i believe that´s not possible, because it would be easy to abuse it for incentivizing - which is not allowed.

Comment: let us know if you have found an update

Comment: @Nilabja Unfortunately not. It seem that browser share dialog always returning to `onSuccess` is not a bug, but a feature. I'll have to write my code to use `publish_actions` (I'm still not sure how to trigger `publish_actions`).

Comment: just leave a comment here when you succeed @cakan

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I have solved the problem by forcing FB web feed as @John Binary suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way around this problem.
Thing is *postId* is always null when you share with Facebook's app. *PostId* gets through to your onSuccess callback when you share without FB app.
The solution is to force your application to use web feed and not FB app for sharing:

```
shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);
```